# how to list all files in current directory

Tags: haskell, file-io, directory

What I want is to write a Haskell function to return the files of current directory e.g

Change the current directory to

```
 :cd c:/code/haskell
```

Then write a function which returns the files in a set e.g

```
 [x | x <-getDirectoryContents ]
```

**Edited:**

I have wrote a function sth like this which lists files 
 (ref: http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputdirectory/index.html)

```
import Directory 

main = _dir "/tmp/FOO"

_dir _path =do
    setCurrentDirectory _path
    _cd <- getCurrentDirectory
    print _cd
    _file <- getDirectoryContents _cd
    print _file
```

so calling _dir "c:/code/haskell" will list all files + directory names (non-recursive) . What I want now is to  call this in a predicate function, for example:

```
[ x| x <- _dir  "c:/code/haskell" | x start with 'haskell_' ]
```

so I can apply a filter on file name

Comment: Do you need to change the current directory? `getDirectoryContents` takes a directory as a parameter.

Comment: I need a function to list all the files in give directory and call that within the  SET PREDICATE and apply some filter to just list names which satisfy certain condition . Thanks

Comment: Those underscores are so ugly...

Comment: @monadic ...and more to the point, underscore generally means "throw away", so I (and I'm sure most Haskellers) read them as unused variables.

Comment: @stusmith: That's how GHC treats them too. The option [`-fwarn-unused-matches`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0-latest/html/users_guide/options-sanity.html) ignores names beginning with an underscore.

Comment: @hammar - Ah I didn't realise it was /all/ names beginning with an underscore. I thought it was just a single underscore for unused matches. You learn something every day...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It seems you are looking for:

```
getDirectoryContents :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
```

Refer : http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/directory-1.0.1.1/System-Directory.html#1

Comment: [x |x <- getDirectoryContents :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]] returns following error Couldn't match expected type `[t0]'
            with actual type `FilePath -> IO [FilePath]' ... I am new to Haskell , please consider me newbie

Comment: @sakhunzai: try `getDirectoryContents "."` on the GHCi prompt. If that works, then learn about the `IO` monad.

Comment: What I posted was a function signature :).. unfortunately I don't have haskell on this system.. I hope someone from the gr8 haskell community will give you the the exact code

Comment: Just to add.. in haskell it won't be same as in other programming languages you have used.. there are different concepts involved and as you are learning haskell I would suggest you to learn those concepts and then try out the code, otherwise you will get confused. A great starting book can be : http://learnyouahaskell.com/

Comment: Thanks Ankur and larsmans , I have sth like this now :`import Directory 

main = _dir "/tmp/FOO"

_dir _path =do
 setCurrentDirectory _path
 _cd <- getCurrentDirectory
 print _cd
 _file <- getDirectoryContents _cd
 print _file`

Answer (score 12):

How about the following:

```
import Data.List
import System.Directory

main = do all <- getDirectoryContents "/tmp/FOO"
          let filtered = filter (isPrefixOf "haskell") all
          print filtered
```

Comment: `liftM` often cleans things up nicely (imo):  `print =<< liftM (filter (isPrefixOf "haskell")) (getDirectoryContents ".")` (EDIT: But yes, stusmith's code is simpler for beginning Haskellers to understand)

Comment: all most done ! `getFiles :: String -> String -> IO ()
getFiles dp flt = do
 files <- getDirectoryContents dp;
 let filtered = filter (isPrefixOf flt) files
 print filtered`  I am not understanding why everyone is pointing me to print file names to console directly . Is is possible to get the files names CAST as string and store it into a variable and output it using some function other than PRINT . What I understand is that print is directly echos the files names as String array to console. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

All that you have to do to write a function that returns all the files in the current dir is the following:

```
import System.Directory

filesInCurDir = getCurrentDirectory >>= getDirectoryContents
```

The >>= operator is the monad sequencing operator with value passing. This is best described here http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/monads.html.

If you are going to use this inside ghci:

```
let filesInCurDir = getCurrentDirectory >>= getDirectoryContents
```

you can check that the function is of type `filesInCurDir :: IO [FilePath]` thus keeping the "monadic nature".

Thus if you want to further filter the files you can do:

```
let filteredFilesInCurDir = 
    getCurrentDirectory >>= 
    getDirectoryContents >>= 
    \files -> return [ x | x <- files, (length x) > 10 ]
```

If you want pass the filter each time:

```
let filterFilesInCurDir f = 
    getCurrentDirectory >>= 
    getDirectoryContents >>= 
    \files -> return [ x | x <- files, f x ]
```

which is the same as:

```
let filteredFilesInCurDir f = 
    getCurrentDirectory >>= 
    getDirectoryContents >>= 
    return . filter f
```

and you can use it like:

```
filterFilesInCurDir (\x -> (length x) > 2)
```

Answer (score 5):

First Point: The expression `[x | x <- lst]` is exactly the same as `lst`, so if `lst` is a list, then this use of a list comprehension is not necessary.

Second: for  `[x | x <-getDirectoryContents ]` to work, the value `getDirectoryContents` should be a list. But that's not the case! `getDirectoryContents` is an IO-value.

You can use this function in the following way (inside a monadic expression):

```
do 
  files <- getDirectoryContents "."
  print files
```

(or - inside ghci - use: `do; files <- getDirectoryContents "."; print files`)

(`files` has type  `[FilePath]` and the while expression has type `IO ()`)

Comment: Thanks phyinfo, that is better than mine( see my Edits) . Can we write a that within the predicate so we can apply a filter on name . Thanks again for your help

Comment: or, cleaner in my opinion, `getDirectoryContents "." >>= print`

Comment: @ sakhunzai: if you want to filter the files with a predicate `pred`, than you can do the following: `do; files <- getDirectoryContents; print $ filter pred files`

Comment: Prettier output is `mapM_ print files`.

Answer (score 5):

[`filemanip`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/filemanip) package offers a
more generalized and flexible functions for this particular task.

I.e. listing regular files from a given directory

```
> :m + System.FilePath.Find
> :t find always (fileType ==? RegularFile)
find always (fileType ==? RegularFile) :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
```

This package is windows-compatible (since it depends on `unix-compat` instead
of just `unix`) and also have neat self-descriptive haddocs.

Comment: filemanip provides a fast way of listing directories (e.g. by defining a recursive predicate and/or the lazy listing)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach using `Control.Applicative`:

```
import Control.Applicative
import System.Directory

isRegularFileOrDirectory :: FilePath -> Bool
isRegularFileOrDirectory f = f /= "." && f /= ".."

main :: IO ()
main = do
  fileNames <- filter isRegularFileOrDirectory <$> getDirectoryContents "."
  putStrLn $ show $ fileNames
```

Comment: ah perfect one , thanks , it gives me : `getDirectoryContents "../"
[".","..",".DS_Store","Clojure","Haskell","Java","Mobile","nll","Phing"]`

Comment: @sakhunzai: You're welcome. Obviously you can replace `isRegularFileOrDirectory` with your predicate of choice.